# select phone numbers from one column into multiple columns sql server query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to select or split phone number from on column into multiple columns.

```
ID  PHONE
1   9701245929, 9701245929,9701245929
2   66663333, 66663333 ,66663333
3   9701245931, 9701245931
4   9701245932, 9701245932
5   26668888, 26668888
6   48228899, 48228899
7   88229933, 88229933
```

I want this OUTPUT

```
ID  PHONE       Phone2       Phone3     
1   9701245929  9701245929  9701245929
2   66663333    66663333    66663333
3   9701245931  9701245931  
4   9701245932  9701245932  
5   26668888    26668888
6   48228899    48228899     
7   88229933    88229933
```

This is my view i want to edit it to give me that OutPut

```
SELECT        contactfk, STUFF
 ((SELECT        ', ' + CAST(Deviceinfo AS VARCHAR(20)) [text()]
  FROM            device
  WHERE        ContactFK = t .contactfk order by devicetypefk FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ' ') DeviceList
 FROM            Device t
 GROUP BY contactfk
```

This is Device table sample data

```
devicePK   ContactFK   DevicetypeFK   DeviceInfo
  1             1          3          9701245929
  2             1          3          9701245929
  3             2          1          66663333
```

Comment: Please show us sample data from `device` table.

Comment: The *real* solution here, however, is fix your design. 1 row per phone number, not 1 column with delimited values, nor multiple columns.

Comment: @Squirrel  I updated the question with Device Table sample data

Comment: Looks like you need PIVOTing. Search for it in this site. Lots of example